# Migrating MS Access 2007 db to Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, ms-access, export

I'm trying to use the SSMS migration tool to a newly fresh database on the SQL server and I get bunch of errors that I can't understand.

any suggestions for a better way, or to direct me to solve the problem ?

Thanks

> - Copying to [dbo].[Vehicle$] (Error)
>     Messages
>     Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>     An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid date format".
>     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with input column "CardExpireDate" (136) on input "Destination Input" (93). The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
>     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Destination Input" (93)" failed because error code 0xC020907A occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "Destination Input" (93)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - Vehicle$" (80) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (93). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
>     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - Vehicle$" (1) returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think it wasn't that obvious, but I figured out there is a problem with the Date data type!

I create a table with same Fields on the SQL Server, but I changed the `smalldate` time Data Type to `NvarChar(250)`. Later I imported to the Table using proper mapping!

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Access apparently has allowed you to stored Date Data in the CardExpiredDate column that doesn't convert or translate to the data type that SSMS is trying to use. I would check that table to see if you can find anything wrong with the values stored there.

You have fields named with a string character in them, like Vehicle$. I highly recommend you don't use any symbols in your field names. Removing these might fix all of your errors.

I think the SSMS tool is your best bet unless your database is trivial, in which case you might be better off building it in SQL Server from scratch.